# Finding all node_cut of cardinality k in a graph with networkx

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory, networkx, connectivity

The networkx function `minimum_node_cut(G)` returns a set of nodes of minimum cardinality that disconnects G. But it only returns one set even if ome other solutions could exist.
I was wondering how to get all these minimum_node_cuts for a given graph G.

And in extension, how to get all node cuts of cardinality k?

I can't think of an algorithm that could compute this efficiently. Does it exist a better method than the naive one that would consists of try each combination of k nodes and checking if G is disconnected?

EDIT: I really like David Eisenstat answer but I can't implement it.. I tried that but I get an error which might be due to something wrong in the recursivity and can't figure what it is. Here is the code:

```
def all_small_cuts(G, k, S=set()): 
    try:
        kappa = nx.node_connectivity(G)
    except nx.NetworkXPointlessConcept:
        return

    if kappa > k - len(S):
        return
    if kappa == 0:  # disconnected
        yield S
    if len(S) < k:
        for node in G.nodes():
            G.remove_node(node)
            S.update(set(str(node)))
            for el in all_small_cuts(G, k, S):
                yield el
```

I just replaced `yield from` since I'm working with python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your performance requirements are, but it's possible to do a lot better than exponential without writing much new code. Suppose that we have a closure `node_connectivity` such that, when `U` is a set of nodes, `node_connectivity(U)` is the connectivity of the induced subgraph on `U`. There's a recursive enumeration strategy for the cuts of cardinality of at most `k`. (Warning: not tested.)

```
def all_small_cuts(U, k, S={}):  # U is the set of vertices
                                 # whose inclusion in S
                                 # is not yet decided
    kappa = node_connectivity(U)
    if kappa > k - len(S):
        return
    if kappa == 0:  # disconnected already
        yield S
    if len(S) < k:
        for v in U:
            yield from all_small_cuts(U - {v}, k, S | {v})
```

This enumerates the relevant cuts with polynomial delay by pruning the branches of the recursion tree that won't yield any results.

There's a lot of room for improvement here, since the flow problems underlying the connectivity test have a rich combinatorial structure.

Comment: I edited my question with python code but I can't make the algorithm working even if it seems promising and quite efficient..

Comment: @ThomasReynaud Not completely familiar with networkx, but you might need to copy G before removing the node and recursing, so that the subsequent iterations have the first node in the graph still.

Answer (score 0):

In the recently released NetworkX 1.10 we added an implementation of Kanevsky’s neat algorithm [1] for finding all minimum-size node cut-sets of a graph. The function is named [nx.all_node_cuts](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.connectivity.kcutsets.all_node_cuts.html), it returns a generator of node cut sets of cardinality equal to the node connectivity of G. Thus if you don't need all node cuts but only one good enough according to some arbitrary criteria, you can stop computing them as soon as you find it.

[1] Kanevsky, A. (1993). Finding all minimum-size separating vertex sets in a graph. Networks 23(6), 533–541. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230230604/abstract

Comment: Is there a simple way to modify this fonction in order to get the node cut sets of cardinality k with k>node connectivity of G?

Comment: I think that "node cut sets of cardinality k with k > node connectivity of G" is not well defined. Node connectivity is equal to the minimum number of nodes that must be removed to disconnect G. A minimum node cut set is a set of nodes that disconnect G that only contains the minimum number of nodes possible to actually disconnect G. Thus, the cardinality of a minimum node cut set is equal to the node connectivity of G. If you want a node cut set with cardinality greater than node connectivity of G, you can find a minimum node cut set, and then add **any other node of G** to the node cut set.

Comment: @JordiTorrents I disagree with this viewpoint.There are vertex cuts with cardinality greater than the connectivity, yet their all subsets are not minimum vertex cuts. They are not necessarily derived by adding some vertices to a minimum vertex cut.